# Как сделать чтобы кто-то отмечал роль в определенном канале и он получал эту роль на Discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Например кто-то отметит в канале  #роли @123 и бот выдавал бы роль @123 этому человеку

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе можно через `on_message`

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    role = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=role_id)
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.text_channels, id=channel_id)
    if message.content == role.mention:
        if message.channel == channel:
            await message.author.add_roles(role)
            return await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} Вам добавлена роль {role.name}')
```